# Weblogic work manager Stuck Thread Action wlst.sh

Tags: weblogic, wlst

In Weblogic, how can I change Work Manager's Stuck-Thread-Action using WLST and Jython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as I share below.

`cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName) cmo.setIgnoreStuckThreads(true)`

Answer (score 0):

WLST uses [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) not Python. You can use the below script to change the stuck thread action.

```
admin_user = "weblogic"
admin_pass = "password"
admin_server_url = "t3://localhost:7001"
managed_server_name = "myserver"

connect(admin_user,admin_pass,admin_server_url)
edit()
startEdit()

cd('/Servers/'+managed_server_name+'/OverloadProtection/'+managed_server_name)

cmo.setPanicAction('no-action')
# cmo.setPanicAction('force-shutdown')
# cmo.setPanicAction('admin-state')

cmo.setFailureAction('no-action')
# cmo.setFailureAction('force-shutdown')
# cmo.setFailureAction('admin-state')

save()
activate()
```

For editing other attributes for Stuck Thread use below :

```
cd('/Servers/'+managed_server_name)
cmo.setStuckThreadMaxTime(300)
```

For more information you can read documentation for OverloadProtectionMBean from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I'm creating new work manager here.I want to Stuck Thread Action set "ignore stuck threads" when I creating work manager at the same time.

Comment: The GUI option  'Ignore, take no action' corresponds to value 'no-action' in WLST for cmo.setFailureAction()

Comment: a section of my code as below
`cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/')
create(workManagerName,'WorkManagers')
cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name='+svr+',Type=Cluster')], ObjectName))
save()
cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
bean=getMBean('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/Capacities/' + CapacityThreadConstraintName)
cmo.setCapacity(bean)`

Comment: I want to changes parameter in wlst                                                             
-Stuck Thread Action: Use server default behavior --> Ignore stuck threads

for example ;                                                                                                          
-------cd('edit:/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/WorkManagers/' + workManagerName)
bean=getMBean('/SelfTuning/' + domainName + '/MinThreadsConstraints/' + minThreadConstraintName)
cmo.setMinThreadsConstraint(bean)------